# XSL - How to move all namespaces to root

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, jdeveloper, bpel

I'm working with Oracle SOA Suite 12c, and I'm new to XSLT.
As part of my current project, I need to move all of the namespaces declared in the XML doc to the root element. 
I have been trying to do it in XSL, but haven't been able to find the correct structure.

This is my current code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>   

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="{name(.)}" namespace="{namespace-uri(.)}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="descendant::*/namespace::*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which get me from

```
<a>
  <rnxp:b xmlns:rnxp="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.apps.aia.xml">dadas</rnxp:b>
</a>
```

to

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<a>
  <rnxp:b>dadas</rnxp:b>
</a>
```

being my desired output

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<a xmlns:rnxp="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.apps.aia.xml">
  <rnxp:b>dadas</rnxp:b>
</a>
```

Can anyone please help me figure out how to achieve this?

**EDIT1:**

I went through the message I was using as input and noticed that the transformation is not working because the same namespace is being declared more than once. So my goal here would be to "normalize" the xml, having all the namespaces declared once at the root level.

Comment: Works fine for me with Saxon 9 at http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/948Fn59.

Comment: It might be related to the way the XML processor in Oracle SOA Suite works. So I'm looking for ways to accomplish the same result using different sets of instructions.

Comment: If the result you have shown is as posted then that tool is broken as it does not even manage to produce namespace well-formed output.